# How to use jsdoc to declare a nodejs variable type in visual studio code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

For example, this is correct:

```
const net = require('net');
const Socket = net.Socket;
/**@type {Socket} */
var s;
s.setTimeout(0);
```

But these not correct:

```
const net = require('net');
/**@type {NodeJS.Socket} */
var s1; //the type is 'interface Socket' not 'class Socket'

/**@type {typeof net.Socket} */
var s2; //the type is 'interface Socket' not 'class Socket'

/**@type {net.Socket} */  //Can't find namespace "net"
var s3;
```

So, how can I declare a `Socket` without extra `const Socket = net.Socket;`

Comment: Wondering the same thing. Please let me know if you find the answer.